# Understanding the identity $f(g)=f \circ g$ where $g \in C(X)$ and $f$ holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma(g)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I'm studying analytic functional calculus right now but I have the feeling that I didn't understand the topic very good since I have troubles solving problems from the book of Conway (A course on functional calculus).

I wanna solve the following problem, where I don't understand the difference between $f(g)$ and $f \circ g$:

Let $C(X)$ be the Banach algebra of complex valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space $X$. Assume $g \in C(X)$ and $f$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the spectrum  $\sigma(g)$ of $g$ ($f \in Hol(\sigma(g))$). The exercise is to show that $f(g)=f \circ g$.

Comment: You need to review [the definition of $f(g)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus), while $f\circ g$ is the function such that $f\circ g(z)=f(g(z))$.

Comment: Since $f(g)(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(t)}{t-g(z)}dt$ for certain $\gamma$. See the article. What you need is to show that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(t)}{t-g(z)}dt=f(g(z))$ for all $z\in X$. This follows from Cauchy's integral formula applied to $f$ and the point $g(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $f(g)$ is.

$f(g)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma}f(z)(z-g)^{-1} dz$,

where $ \Gamma$ is a collection of closed and rectifiable curves as in Prop. 4.4 in Conway's book.

Observe that $f(g) \in C(X)$. Now compare , for $x \in X$:

$(f(g))(x)$ and $f(g(x))$.

By Cauchy we have

$f(g(x))=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma}f(z)(z-g(x))^{-1} dz$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you very much! Right after that exercise there is another where one has to show that $(g \circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$ when $x$ is an element of an arbitrary Banach algebra and $f$ is holomorphic on the spectrum of $x$ and g is holomorphic on $f(\sigma(x))$. Could you please give me some hints how to apply the definitions of $f(g)$ in this case to show the identity?

Comment: Fred, how would you write$f(g)(x)$? The only way I see is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int f(z)(z-g)^{-1}dz(x)$...